# How to avoid Azure DevOps Multi-Stage YAML Pipelines execution jumps between stages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have multiple Azure YAML multi-stage Pipelines consisting 3-4 stages each.

We use Microsoft Hosted Agents for all.

Currently, when **Pipeline A** is triggered, it starts executing **Stage 1** of the pipeline.
Meanwhile, if **Pipeline B**, **Pipeline C**.. are triggered, then after execution of **Pipeline A - Stage 1** is completed, it skips to **Pipeline B - Stage 1** execution and then either comes back to **Pipeline A - Stage 2** or goes to **Pipeline C - Stage 1** based on the queue order.

How do I avoid this situation?
I want **Pipeline A** when triggered to complete it's all stages and then switch to other pipelines and follow the same approach for rest.

I want to avoid these jumps between stages of multiple pipelines in queue.

Comment: may i know if the answer below helps? Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple individual pipelines, it's NOT supported to restrict stages in one pipeline starting after stages in another pipeline complete.

Microsoft-hosted agents are assigned to run pipeline jobs based on the availability and compatibility of the agents. When multiple pipelines are triggered, they are added to a queue and processed in the order they were received. When job in pipeline A complete, job in pipeline B or C could start due to the order received.

Even for same pipeline which has multiple stages, they won't wait and jump as well. You can find more details in official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-queuing-policies):

[image]

If you would like the feature, you can raise a use voice ticket here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest.